# How to store variable in an AngularJS HTML template?

Tags: angularjs

How can I store values to variable for example on click in angular? I have the following code which doesn't save the value into variable:

**HTML:**

```
<div ng-app='app'>
    <a ng-controller="MyController" href="#" ng-click="variable = 1">

    </a>
    {{variable}}
</div>
```

**Controller:**

```
var app = angular.module('app',[]);

app.controller('MyController', function($scope)
{
});
```

[jsfiddle code](http://jsfiddle.net/ybavzec4/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to initialize the variable. See http://plnkr.co/edit/dmSNVJ3BGIeaWaddKtZe

```
<body ng-app="">
  <button ng-click="count = 1" ng-init="count='not set'">
  Increment
</button>
<span>
  count: {{count}}
</span>
</body>
```

Answer (score 5):

Your variable binding `{{variable}}` should be inside controller's scope. So move `ng-controller` to an element that will contain variable binding.

Answer (score 2):

Use a function to set the variable:

HTML:

```
<div ng-app='app'>
    <a ng-controller="MyController" href="#" ng-click="setVariable()">

    </a>
    {{variable}}
</div>
```

Controller:

```
var app = angular.module('app',[]);

app.controller('MyController', function($scope)
{
    $scope.setVariable = function() {
        $scope.variable = 1;
    }
});
```

Comment: Note that variable binding is out of controller's scope.

Answer (score 2):

Your syntax is correct, what went wrong is you put your controller declaration in the wrong place.

You just need move it to the outer layer, no need for `ng-init` or function (but might be a better practice):

```
<div ng-app='app' ng-controller="MyController">
    <a  href="#" ng-click="variable=1">
    click me!
    </a>
    {{variable}}
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ybavzec4/3/